# How to duplicate the entire gatsbyjs app into an additional directory on compile for theming

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to have two versions of the gatsby generated application so that I can theme one dark and one light. The best way that I can think to do this is with a `/dark/` in the url to point to the dark themed app. I considered doing a query param to set a class, but query params get lost when navigating around and I don't want to have to pass it around. I also considered the react router but feel like there has to be a way to just duplicate it. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Have you considered having a simple switch between dark/light mode? There is no real need to duplicate the whole app in order to enable this feature.

Comment: @PowellYe - can you tell me how you think that would work? I need to set a body class to set it to dark mode. I can't do media queries. I need it to persist. Thats why I thought the url would be ideal.

Comment: Take a look at this guide, for instance => https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-01-31-using-react-context-api-with-gatsby/

Comment: Excellent @PowellYe! I don't actually need all the API stuff - just the approach. I'll use localstorage that I set from a url paramater so that it persists through the app. Seems it should have come to me sooner but thanks for your inspiration!

Comment: Glad it helped : )